# Change color of input box when input box is empty HTML using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

am using `bootstrap.css` file for my form and in input box i have added a option `required=""`

- so that when client submit data before entering data in the`required=""` text box
- form will show warning message that please fill that form
- and this is my `<input type="text" name="type" id="type-1" value="buy" required="">`

### now my question is

- how do i make that input box red when warning box appear

Comment: you do not want to use jQuery Validation Plugin?

Comment: i have validation plugin

Answer (score 0):

you can do this simply with jquery see my example below

```
<input type="text" id="demo"/>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="submit"/>

$("#btn").click(function(){
    var text = $("#demo").val();
    if(text === ""){
        $("#demo").css({"border" : "1px solid red", "color" : "red"}).val("this is required");
    }else{
        // the function you want to do with the form
    }
});
```

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/q19u95gv/)

you would need to build on this a little but it gives you the basic idea

**EDIT** i edited the jsfiddle to work better

[New JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/q19u95gv/1/)